# Is it possible to exclude the total row (margins) from styling (subset) in a pandas pivot table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table, styling

So for example I ran a .pivot_table call with margins=True. Now I want to run .style.bar on it but the total of each column always sets the max value for the bar so it kinda looks nondescript. Any way around this?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"A": ["foo", "foo", "foo", "foo", "foo",
                      "bar", "bar", "bar", "bar"],
                "B": ["one", "one", "one", "two", "two",
                      "one", "one", "two", "two"],
                "C": ["small", "large", "large", "small",
                      "small", "large", "small", "small",
                     "large"],
                "D": [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]})
df = df.pivot_table(values='D', index=['A','B'], columns=['C'], aggfunc=np.sum, margins=True)
df = df.style.bar(subset=['small','large','All'],align='mid',color='red')
from IPython.core.display import HTML
HTML(df.render())
```

Basically 7, 6, and 13 should have been the maxes (second row of pivot table)

Comment: Please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I have included one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Much easier than I expected. Just needed to call this before running the style command

```
df = df.drop(index='All', axis=0)
```